# Add existing labels to a new or existing card

Tags: manatee.trello

I just started using Manatee.Trello but I managed to get most everything I need working including adding new cards and updating existing.

I'm attempting to add a label that already exists on Trello to a card using Manatee.Trello.

```
CardID = "cardIDHere";
var card = new Card(CardID);
card.Name = strCardTitle;
card.Description = strCardDesc;
var list = new List("listIDHere");
card.List = list;
var member = new Member("MemberIDHere");
var label = new Label(board,"blue",DateTime.Now,"ID-Here","ProdIssues",1);
card.Labels.Add(label);
```

Can someone show the proper way to create an instance of that Label class for an existing label?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Label` has an internal constructor.  The only way to get an instance of a label is through the `Board.Labels` collection.

I did this because a label only makes sense in the context of a board.  Each board defines its labels, and a label without a board is meaningless.

To get your code working, you just need to access the board's label collection and select the one you want to apply to the card.

```
...
var label = card.Board.Labels.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Color == LabelColor.Blue);
if (label != null)
    card.Labels.Add(label);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you for the help @gregsdennis and for all your work on Manatee.Trello!  It's working great!  The only thing I have left to figure out is how to properly use the card.Labels.Contains to see if a label exists before trying to add it.

Comment: Use the `Any()` method (provided by LINQ) on the label collection and provide a predicate which will match your label.